# How to execute a function?

Tags: f#

I read a book called Real World Functional Programming with F# and C# and there is an example that goes like this

```
open System

let readInput() =      
    let s = Console.ReadLine()      
    let (succ, num) = Int32.TryParse(s)
    if (succ) then  
        Some(num)
    else          
        None

let readAndAdd1() =    
    match (readInput()) with 
    | None    -> None    
    | Some(n) -> 
        match (readInput()) with       
        | None    -> None       
        | Some(m) ->         
            Some(n + m)

printfn "Result - %A" readAndAdd1
```

It should ask you for two numbers and then add them together. But I don't seem to get it working. When I tried this in LinqPad even got an error when I typed `readInput()`. When I typed just `readInput` it asked me for the first value but not for the second one. In the F# Interactive it works but it prints out `Result - <fun:it@20>`

How can I run this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying

```
printfn "Result - %A" readAndAdd1
```

in F# interactive you provides printfn with identifier 'readAndAdd1' which is a function.
If you need to print result of function call you should call this function like this:

```
printfn "Result - %A" (readAndAdd1())
```

in this case F# interactive will wait for two inputs and will print result afterward.
F# interactive output:

```
> printfn "Result - %A" (readAndAdd1());;
2
3
Result - Some 5
val it : unit = ()
>
```